# Increase tap area of UIBarButtonitem to the left far side of navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the following code to add the back button bar item to the navigation bar.

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
        UIImage *image = [mysdk.icon.backArrow make];
        UIButton *back = [self.class buttonForBarItemByImage:image size:size];
        back.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        UIBarButtonItem *backArrow = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
        [back addTarget:backArrow action:@selector(backArrow_onClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

+ (UIButton *) buttonForBarItemByImage:(UIImage *)image size:(CGSize)size {
    UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [back setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGSize buttonSize = size;
    back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);
    return back;
}
```

As you see in the following image the button is added. The image of the button is in the middle of the grey area. The grey area is the tap area.

[image]

As you see i circle with red color the area that is still with yellow. So i need to make this area tappable. The button image should not move just increase the tap area from the left. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Extend the button with an alpha channel area.

Comment: What do you mean extend the button with an alpha channel area?

Comment: alpha=transparent. Can also be some CALayer that goes outside the Views size and still reports back to your Control/View. But easier as El Tomato possibly meant, just extend the Controls size to the left and shift the graphics to the right so the empty space is "alpha".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subclassed `UINavigationBar`:

**MyNavBar.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyNavBar : UINavigationBar

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**MyNavBar.m**

```
#import "MyNavBar.h"

@implementation MyNavBar

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // get the custom view (the UIButton)
    UIView *v = self.topItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView;
    if (v) {
        // convert the button's frame to its superview coordinate space
        CGRect r = [self convertRect:v.frame toView:v.superview];
        // convert the point to the button's coordinate space
        CGPoint p = [self convertPoint:point toView:v];
        // if p is inside r
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(r, p)) {
            // return the custom view
            return v;
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
@end
```